# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage is returning null when trying to get image uri

Tags: java, android, image, uri

I need to get the uri from image bitmap so i use this method to get the uri

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    fixMediaDir();
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

but `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` return **null** in some devices

**note**: I have added permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and added the **runtime permissions** for camera and storage as well.

I also added `FileProvider` in the manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mvc.imagepicker.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource"/>
    </provider>
```

**notice** that the authorities on the provider is **`"com.mvc.imagepicker.provider"`** because i use **Mariovc/ImagePicker** and used the same authorities like his.

I saw in other posts, people mentioned to add this code before calling

> MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

```
public void fixMediaDir() {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Log.d("a111", "sdcard: "+sdcard);
    if (sdcard != null) {
        File mediaDir = new File(sdcard, "DCIM/Camera");
        if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
            mediaDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

so it will create a directory if not excists, but it didnt help me.

so im posting this here maybe i'm missing something else and somebody can help me out.

Comment: Use `FileProvider`, please.

Comment: I forget to mention, but i added file provider to the manifest

Comment: Well, then perhaps use `FileProvider`, rather than `insertImage()`.

Comment: I'm using ImagePicker and it returns a bitmp image and i'm trying to get the uri from bitmap. but as i said i'm getting an exception from getImageUri method.
@CommonsWare can you show me how to get image uri by using FileProvider and not insertImage?

Comment: Write the bitmap to a file. Serve the file using `FileProvider`. Use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to hand to the other app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are saying it is returning null in some devices, I think this is because the permissions are not provided. Setting permissions in manifest only specify the permissions required. It is up to the device or the operating system to grant them. `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are not provided by default in some operating systems. Try this:

```
private final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, 
                                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
                                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345; //Some random number


...
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreenActivity.this, permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreenActivity.this, permissions[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreenActivity.this, permissions[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreenActivity.this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    ...
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length == 3 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Permission granted!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Necessary permissions not granted...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Add this to the first activity in your app. This will ask the user to grant the permissions if not already provided.

Comment: I said that i have added the runtime permission also. runtime permission isn't my problem.

Comment: My bad, after checking the storage permission, turns out that i was missing to provide the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. so after granting the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE it worked.

Comment: Already have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> but still not work.